# Why MSI installer queries registry for all installed certificates?

Tags: windows-installer, registry, wix3.5

I had a problem with my msi installer on a client.

Kaspersky has blocked it, because MSI was accessing protected registry paths in

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\
```

MSI is digitally signed with certificate, which was signed by Global sign.

I checked installation via Process Monitor and it looks like msi is accessing every certificate in system.

[Screenshot of Process Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cspx0.png)

I need to know, why does it do that?

Is there any way to disable it? I am using wix toolset.

Comment: Do you have any custom actions in this MSI? Open it in Orca and check the CustomAction table.

Comment: Yes, it has custom actions, but none of them reads the registry by path
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\

Comment: Can this MSI be put somewhere to view? Hard to guess otherwise. Are you using any of WiX's built-in custom actions or features?

Comment: No, i can`t put it in public view. I use only WixFailWhenDeferred for msi testing purposes. I think this problem is more likely about msiexec low level logic.
I also tested another msi (Epic games store MSI installer) and Process Monitor showed the same accesses to certificates

Comment: For an MSI installation to enumerate all certificate might be standard behavior, but I honestly have never tested. I would recommend you upload all your files AND your custom action DLL to https://www.virustotal.com/ to check for any malware hits. Also upload your whole, compiled MSI - if you can. And avoid uploading anything sensitive such as private keys (included from your source folder by accident for example), files with passwords, license files or anything like that.

Comment: I cannot upload my installer anywhere. I checked it with Kaspersky antivirus - and it was ok.

Comment: You can reproduce this with some other msi. I tesed on EGS (https://store.epicgames.com/ru/download)